# ionic/angular share data between pages

Tags: angular, navigation, ionic3, storage

I cant figure out how to achieve the following result.

I have 2 pages. The first one

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>{{evId}} - {{items.list_code}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items.List_group">
    <ion-label>{{item.GroupName}}</ion-label>
    <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="goToTemplate(evId,item)">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full type="button" (click)="saveData()" >Save</button>
</ion-content>
```

and the second

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>{{empl}} - {{items.GroupName}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items.List_field">
    <ion-label>{{item.Field_Name}} - {{item.Field_Type}}</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea *ngIf='item.Field_Type==="textarea"' placeholder="Enter a description" ></ion-textarea>
    <ion-checkbox *ngIf='item.Field_Type==="chk"' ></ion-checkbox>
    <ion-select *ngIf='item.Field_Type==="chklist"' multiple="true" (change)="storeField(item.id,$event)">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let option of item.Field_Default_Values" [value]="option.id" >{{option.Value}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    <ion-select *ngIf='item.Field_Type==="ddl"' >
      <ion-option *ngFor="let option of item.Field_Default_Values" [value]="option.id" >{{option.Value}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    ...
</ion-content>
```

the first one builds dynamically a menu based on the received object: clicking on the button oh each line the app routes to the second page, creating dynamically a list of components depending on their type.

Now I'm struggling trying to save data in the second page, bring them back on the first page, and giving them the structure I need to send the object I need to save to the service.

Each Item on the second page has an id coming from the object received by the service.

```
{
 ...
 Field_Name:"A/C Type"
 Field_Type:"chklist"
 id:15
 IsMandatory:true
 Sequence:1
 ...
}
```

At the end on the navigation I need to end up on the first page having an object like this

```
"list_reportfield": [
  {
    "Field_id": 0,
    "List_Values": ["string"]
  }
]
```

containing a list of all the ids and their values, to be sent to the saving services.

I would like to find an elegant way to achieve this result.. something as near as possible to the best practice to do this.

Anybody giving me an hint?
thank U all guys so much

Comment: If you're using Ionics navController, you can pass data using the push method: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#pushing-a-view

Comment: the problem is pushing back, not supported yet

Comment: I think you want events: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the saved data from second page to first page using couple of approaches:

## Solution-1:

You can implement [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/). So, in the second page, you can do your stuff and publish the data. And in the first page, you can subscribe to the event and get the published data from second page.

```
    import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
    
    // first page (listen for the user created event after function is called)
    constructor(public events: Events) {
      events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
        // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
        console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
      });
     }

      // second page (publish an event when a user is created)
    constructor(public events: Events) {}
    createUser(user) {
      console.log('User created!')
      this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
    }
```

## Solution-2:

You can open your second page using [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) and from modal controller, you can send data when dismissing the modal. In the first page, you can get the sent data in **onDidDismiss**.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(...)
class HomePage {

 constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

 }

 presentProfileModal() {
   let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile, { userId: 8675309 });
   profileModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
   });
   profileModal.present();
 }

}

@Component(...)
class Profile {

 constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
   
 }

 // return the saved data when dismissing the modal
 saveData() {
   let data = { 'foo': 'bar' };
   this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
 }

}
```